# firebase authentication error nodejs app in docker container running in docker swarm

Tags: node.js, firebase, docker

i am running my application with dockers and i have a weird issue with my express server that uses firebase.

basically when i run it locally everything works fine, but as soon as i get it to run on my docker swarm on aws ec2 instance then it fails connecting to firebase.

i have a module which initializes the connection to firebase like this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        client_email: process.env.FB_CLIENT_MAIL,
        project_id: process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID,
        private_key: process.env.FB_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.FB_URL,
})
```

and i require it to connect to firebase on each of my services.
the ONLY service that has an error is the service on which i host the REST api of my application.

it runs express and exposes the service on port 8080 in the docker-compose file.
when i run the stack on my swarm i get this error:

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN accounts.google.com:443. Error code: EAI_AGAIN\"."}
```

i read a couple of threads about similar issues that involved clock synchronization. but my server and dockers are in sync.

my other services also connect to firebase and they work fine.

more things that i found out:

when i run: `docker exec -it <other container>` and i run my server from it then it works fine.

somehow the exposed port breaks it.

looks like a DNS problem with the docker container, somehow the exposed port makes it not able to ping `google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i found out that my container didn't resolve dns correctly.

i have searched online if other people has a similar issue and i found this thread.

https://github.com/jderusse/docker-dns-gen/issues/21

basically these are the solutions i found :

1.

> I fixed it by adding this { "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"] } in
>   /etc/docker/daemon.json

2. another possibility is adding this to the docker-compose file

`dns: 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

"somehow the exposed port breaks it"

This sounds suspiciously like a firewall issue. Have you configured your cloud provider firewall to allow connections to this port?

Comment: i have added additional information of what i have found out.
and yes, it is exposed and works fine

Comment: Ah I see you edited as I was typing :p. Does the container have an external ip you can curl?

Comment: i have just found the issue and how to resolve it ill comments on my question with an answer